# How to change the color of one cell based on the value of another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In fact I have a column called status (K) which contains two values Y or N. 
I want to  change the background color of another column (J) based on the info from column K.
I want the script to change the color of J to red when K is Y and transparent when K equals N.

I have tried different scenarios on the forum but since I have no notion of java I'm totally blocked.

I need your help please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to use special formatting rules for that but they only apply to the current cell. Thus, you can create a formula to set specific values in column J depending on values on column K and then apply conditional formatting to cells in column J. But of course, this is no different from applying the same to values in column K.

Above I assumed your J column is empty, used only for colors. If you also have data, then you need to update the formula to mix the two.

Comment: Mihai in fact conditional formating cannot be applied since I take the value from another cell and conditional formating in googlme spreadsheet does not let me do that.

Comment: moreover I have found this script but the problem I have with it is that it does not update as I change the values in K
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Red Box');
  var columnK = sheet.getRange(3, 11, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var KValues = columnK.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < KValues.length; i++) {
    if (KValues[i][0] == 'Y') {
      sheet.getRange(i + 3, 10, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('red');
    }
  }
}

Comment: I dont have access to my spreadsheet now but I'll let you know. Thanks anyhow Mihai. Just one other favor when I wanted to add an else at the end of my script I got an error. I want to add an else saying that if if (KValues[i][0] == 'Y') is not true ==> sheet.getRange(i + 3, 10, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('white');
but when I compile it, it bugs on else function!

Comment: If the answer was useful consider voting in it. If not, please tell this so I can update/delete it.

Comment: sorry I didnt know it works like tht. it's done! by the way I have another question can I ask you to take a look at it please?

Comment: Ask it on front page and if anyone sees it he'll answer